# Resize images from portrait to landscape mode in iOS

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, resize, landscape

What is the best way to resize images from portrait to landscape view?

The best way is to change the image when you turn the device? or use the coordinates of autosizing in IB?

thanks for all!

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to add autoresizing mask to your image view like this

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the best way. I do like this

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```